# Javascript Search for a match and output the whole string that the matching word is apart of

Tags: javascript, arrays, search, indexof

how would you go about outputting the found output, including the rest of the string its apart of? The array is just full of strings. Thanks

```
    var searchingfor = document.getElementById('searchfield').value;
        var searchingforinlowerCase = searchingfor.toLowerCase();
        var searchDiv = document.getElementById('searchDiv');
        var convertarraytoString = appointmentArr.toString();
        var arraytolowerCase = convertarraytoString.toLowerCase();
        var splitarrayString = arraytolowerCase.split(',')



        if(search(searchingforinlowerCase, splitarrayString) == true) {
                alert( searchingforinlowerCase + ' was found at index' + searchLocation(searchingforinlowerCase,splitarrayString) + ' Amount of times found = ' +searchCount(searchingforinlowerCase,splitarrayString));


        function search(target, arrayToSearchIn) {

        var i;

          for (i=0; i<arrayToSearchIn.length; i++)
        {   if (arrayToSearchIn[i] == target && target !=="")
        return true;
        }
```

Comment: Return `arrayToSearchIn[i]`  instead of `true` ? Where is `searchLocation` defined ?

Comment: Sorry I didint include the function for finding the location,

Comment: Is requirement to return entire string matched , or only remainder of string matched within array ? Can include example of string to match , `appointmentArr` array at Question ?

Comment: No just a word, so for example if they type in a "america" in the search field and then click search the results should bring back the entire string of  where "america" is found, so the result would bring up any strings with that matching word...etc  First Name: John, Location:"america:

Comment: So a typical string would be like var dummyAppointments = new Array('25/05/2015','0800','0900','TSV5555','America')

Comment: _"So a typical string would be like var dummyAppointments = new Array('25/05/2015','0800','0900','TSV5555','America') "_ ? `dummyAppointments` appear to be array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
if(search(searchingforinlowerCase, appointmentArr) == true) {
                    alert( searchingforinlowerCase + ' was found at index' + searchLocation(searchingforinlowerCase,splitarrayString) + ' Amount of times found = ' +searchCount(searchingforinlowerCase,splitarrayString));


function search(target, arrayToSearchIn) {
var i; 
for (i=0; i<arrayToSearchIn.length; i++)
{   if (arrayToSearchIn[i].indexOf(target >= 0))
        return true;
}
    return false;
}
```

This code will help you find that a match is present. You can update code to display full text where match was found. Original posted code was comparing entire string rather than partial match.

Comment: Ok this finds it, but how do i get the string that its related to be printed out ha?

Comment: Great thanks! now if i wanted to be able to print out multiple matches, would i need to push each match to a new array in the function?

Comment: Awesome! if I were to write these strings to a table, do you have to do it within the function or can you do it through the variable?

Comment: You always separate the computation and display code. It is better to return an array of matched strings from search function and then display all returned in a table.

Comment: How do you return the index and the strings? is it arrayToSearchIn[i] to be returned or just i? or like  return arrayToSearchIn[i],i;

Comment: I rejig'd code to meet your requirements. https://jsfiddle.net/hd5jxn7s/  You cannot return 2 things in a single return statement unless you contain them in some form.

Comment: Thankyou for your help, much appreciated . I Just need to add each string to a table now =)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
var test = 'Hello World';
if (test.indexOf('Wor') >= 0)
{
  /* found substring Wor */
}
```

In your posted code you are converting Array to string and then again converting it back to Array using split(). That is unnecessary. search can be invoked as

```
search(searchingforinlowerCase, appointmentArr);
```

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to be working, I've just tried the method of if (appointmentArr.indexOf(searchingforinlowerCase) >= 0)
 {
  alert("Found")     /* found substring Wor */
 }

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `Array.prototype.filter()` , `String.prototype.indexOf()`

```js
// input string
var str = "america";
// array of strings
var arr = ["First Name: John, Location:'america'", "First Name: Jane, Location:'antarctica'"];
// filter array of strings
var res = arr.filter(function(value) {
  // if `str` found in `value` , return string from `arr`
  return value.toLowerCase().indexOf(str.toLowerCase()) !== -1
});
// do stuff with returned single , or strings from `arr`
console.log(res, res[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will look for a word in an array of strings and return all the strings that match the word. Is this something you are looking for?

```
var a  = ["one word", "two sentence", "three paragraph", "four page", "five chapter", "six section", "seven book", "one, two word", "two,two sentence", "three, two paragraph", "four, two page", "five, two chapter",];

function search(needle, haystack){
    var results = [];
  haystack.forEach(function(str){
        if(str.indexOf(needle) > -1){
            results.push(str);
        }
  });
    return results.length ? results : '';
};

var b = search("word", a);
console.log(b);
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dp5qsavj/) to try.